# Seaborn Clustermap: sort columns by category and add colorbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to make some small modifications to sns.clustermap but I am struggling.

**What I want it to do**

I want to:

1. add a categorical colorbar somewhere to the clustermap for the `col_colors`
2. sort the columns so that the columns of the same category are next to each other

**What I can get it to do**

I can get it to:

1. Add `col_colors` to top of clustermap

**Minimum Working Example**

Code:

```py
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

# category data
cat = iris.species

# dict of {cat: color}
lut = dict(zip(
    cat.unique(), 
    sns.color_palette('mako', cat.unique().size)
))

# corresponding color per column
col_colors = cat.map(lut)

sns.clustermap(
    # try to sort by species and transpose dataframe
    data=iris.sort_values('species').drop(columns='species').T,
    
    metric='correlation',
    
    # don't need to see index labels
    xticklabels=False,
    col_colors=col_colors
)
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

**UPDATE**: I can kind of get a colorbar....? But not sorting

```py
import matplotlib

def get_bbox(grid):
    cbar_spacing = 0.05
    cbar_size = 0.025
    
    heat = grid.ax_heatmap.get_position()
    dend = grid.ax_col_dendrogram.get_position()
    y0 = dend.y0
    y1 = dend.y1
    x0 = heat.x1
    x1 = heat.x1 + cbar_size
    return [[x0, y0], [x1, y1]]


grid = sns.clustermap(
    data=iris.sort_values('species').drop(columns='species').T,
    method='complete',
    metric='euclidean',
    xticklabels=False,
    col_colors=col_colors
)

ax = grid.fig.axes[-2]
handles = [Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', markerfacecolor=v, label=k, markersize=8) for k, v in lut.items()]
ax.legend(title='species', handles=handles,  bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

**What I've looked to for solutions**

0. Seaborn documentation: [link](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html)
1. this semi fancy custom heatmap / cluster map which handles sorting: [link](https://alumni.media.mit.edu/%7Esbates/heatmaps.html)
2. this clustermap which handles colorbar: [link](https://notebooks.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?color_mode=auto&commit=285350bb44d9ab1c61f829c1664f59279ff2c774&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f676973742f616672656e646569726f2f35343135383532626365646339333134623130353865356439333266356332312f7261772f323835333530626234346439616231633631663832396331363634663539323739666632633737342f736561626f726e5f636c75737465726d61705f776974685f6566666f72746c6573735f636f6c6f72626172735f6465636f7261746f722e6970796e62&logged_in=false&nwo=afrendeiro%2F5415852bcedc9314b1058e5d932f5c21&path=seaborn_clustermap_with_effortless_colorbars_decorator.ipynb&repository_id=103071526&repository_type=Gist)
3. this clustermap: [link](https://pdc.cancer.gov/API_documentation/PDC_clustergram.html)

Why these solutions are insufficient:

0. Used it to get `col_colors`. Doesn't handle sorting or adding colorbar
1. This looks nice, but the code is hard to understand and adding the colorbar is nontrivial
2. doesn't run with MWE
3. can't figure out column sorting

**EDIT**: copy-pasta iris data since someone had difficulty using it

```py
values = [[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4, 'setosa'],
 [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3, 'setosa'],
 [5.0, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.1, 'setosa'],
 [5.4, 3.7, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [4.8, 3.4, 1.6, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [4.8, 3.0, 1.4, 0.1, 'setosa'],
 [4.3, 3.0, 1.1, 0.1, 'setosa'],
 [5.8, 4.0, 1.2, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.7, 4.4, 1.5, 0.4, 'setosa'],
 [5.4, 3.9, 1.3, 0.4, 'setosa'],
 [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.3, 'setosa'],
 [5.7, 3.8, 1.7, 0.3, 'setosa'],
 [5.1, 3.8, 1.5, 0.3, 'setosa'],
 [5.4, 3.4, 1.7, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.1, 3.7, 1.5, 0.4, 'setosa'],
 [4.6, 3.6, 1.0, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.1, 3.3, 1.7, 0.5, 'setosa'],
 [4.8, 3.4, 1.9, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.0, 3.0, 1.6, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.0, 3.4, 1.6, 0.4, 'setosa'],
 [5.2, 3.5, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.2, 3.4, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [4.7, 3.2, 1.6, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [4.8, 3.1, 1.6, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.4, 3.4, 1.5, 0.4, 'setosa'],
 [5.2, 4.1, 1.5, 0.1, 'setosa'],
 [5.5, 4.2, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.0, 3.2, 1.2, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.5, 3.5, 1.3, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [4.9, 3.6, 1.4, 0.1, 'setosa'],
 [4.4, 3.0, 1.3, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.1, 3.4, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.0, 3.5, 1.3, 0.3, 'setosa'],
 [4.5, 2.3, 1.3, 0.3, 'setosa'],
 [4.4, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.0, 3.5, 1.6, 0.6, 'setosa'],
 [5.1, 3.8, 1.9, 0.4, 'setosa'],
 [4.8, 3.0, 1.4, 0.3, 'setosa'],
 [5.1, 3.8, 1.6, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [4.6, 3.2, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.3, 3.7, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [5.0, 3.3, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'],
 [7.0, 3.2, 4.7, 1.4, 'versicolor'],
 [6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5, 'versicolor'],
 [6.9, 3.1, 4.9, 1.5, 'versicolor'],
 [5.5, 2.3, 4.0, 1.3, 'versicolor'],
 [6.5, 2.8, 4.6, 1.5, 'versicolor'],
 [5.7, 2.8, 4.5, 1.3, 'versicolor'],
 [6.3, 3.3, 4.7, 1.6, 'versicolor'],
 [4.9, 2.4, 3.3, 1.0, 'versicolor'],
 [6.6, 2.9, 4.6, 1.3, 'versicolor'],
 [5.2, 2.7, 3.9, 1.4, 'versicolor'],
 [5.0, 2.0, 3.5, 1.0, 'versicolor'],
 [5.9, 3.0, 4.2, 1.5, 'versicolor'],
 [6.0, 2.2, 4.0, 1.0, 'versicolor'],
 [6.1, 2.9, 4.7, 1.4, 'versicolor'],
 [5.6, 2.9, 3.6, 1.3, 'versicolor'],
 [6.7, 3.1, 4.4, 1.4, 'versicolor'],
 [5.6, 3.0, 4.5, 1.5, 'versicolor'],
 [5.8, 2.7, 4.1, 1.0, 'versicolor'],
 [6.2, 2.2, 4.5, 1.5, 'versicolor'],
 [5.6, 2.5, 3.9, 1.1, 'versicolor'],
 [5.9, 3.2, 4.8, 1.8, 'versicolor'],
 [6.1, 2.8, 4.0, 1.3, 'versicolor'],
 [6.3, 2.5, 4.9, 1.5, 'versicolor'],
 [6.1, 2.8, 4.7, 1.2, 'versicolor'],
 [6.4, 2.9, 4.3, 1.3, 'versicolor'],
 [6.6, 3.0, 4.4, 1.4, 'versicolor'],
 [6.8, 2.8, 4.8, 1.4, 'versicolor'],
 [6.7, 3.0, 5.0, 1.7, 'versicolor'],
 [6.0, 2.9, 4.5, 1.5, 'versicolor'],
 [5.7, 2.6, 3.5, 1.0, 'versicolor'],
 [5.5, 2.4, 3.8, 1.1, 'versicolor'],
 [5.5, 2.4, 3.7, 1.0, 'versicolor'],
 [5.8, 2.7, 3.9, 1.2, 'versicolor'],
 [6.0, 2.7, 5.1, 1.6, 'versicolor'],
 [5.4, 3.0, 4.5, 1.5, 'versicolor'],
 [6.0, 3.4, 4.5, 1.6, 'versicolor'],
 [6.7, 3.1, 4.7, 1.5, 'versicolor'],
 [6.3, 2.3, 4.4, 1.3, 'versicolor'],
 [5.6, 3.0, 4.1, 1.3, 'versicolor'],
 [5.5, 2.5, 4.0, 1.3, 'versicolor'],
 [5.5, 2.6, 4.4, 1.2, 'versicolor'],
 [6.1, 3.0, 4.6, 1.4, 'versicolor'],
 [5.8, 2.6, 4.0, 1.2, 'versicolor'],
 [5.0, 2.3, 3.3, 1.0, 'versicolor'],
 [5.6, 2.7, 4.2, 1.3, 'versicolor'],
 [5.7, 3.0, 4.2, 1.2, 'versicolor'],
 [5.7, 2.9, 4.2, 1.3, 'versicolor'],
 [6.2, 2.9, 4.3, 1.3, 'versicolor'],
 [5.1, 2.5, 3.0, 1.1, 'versicolor'],
 [5.7, 2.8, 4.1, 1.3, 'versicolor'],
 [6.3, 3.3, 6.0, 2.5, 'virginica'],
 [5.8, 2.7, 5.1, 1.9, 'virginica'],
 [7.1, 3.0, 5.9, 2.1, 'virginica'],
 [6.3, 2.9, 5.6, 1.8, 'virginica'],
 [6.5, 3.0, 5.8, 2.2, 'virginica'],
 [7.6, 3.0, 6.6, 2.1, 'virginica'],
 [4.9, 2.5, 4.5, 1.7, 'virginica'],
 [7.3, 2.9, 6.3, 1.8, 'virginica'],
 [6.7, 2.5, 5.8, 1.8, 'virginica'],
 [7.2, 3.6, 6.1, 2.5, 'virginica'],
 [6.5, 3.2, 5.1, 2.0, 'virginica'],
 [6.4, 2.7, 5.3, 1.9, 'virginica'],
 [6.8, 3.0, 5.5, 2.1, 'virginica'],
 [5.7, 2.5, 5.0, 2.0, 'virginica'],
 [5.8, 2.8, 5.1, 2.4, 'virginica'],
 [6.4, 3.2, 5.3, 2.3, 'virginica'],
 [6.5, 3.0, 5.5, 1.8, 'virginica'],
 [7.7, 3.8, 6.7, 2.2, 'virginica'],
 [7.7, 2.6, 6.9, 2.3, 'virginica'],
 [6.0, 2.2, 5.0, 1.5, 'virginica'],
 [6.9, 3.2, 5.7, 2.3, 'virginica'],
 [5.6, 2.8, 4.9, 2.0, 'virginica'],
 [7.7, 2.8, 6.7, 2.0, 'virginica'],
 [6.3, 2.7, 4.9, 1.8, 'virginica'],
 [6.7, 3.3, 5.7, 2.1, 'virginica'],
 [7.2, 3.2, 6.0, 1.8, 'virginica'],
 [6.2, 2.8, 4.8, 1.8, 'virginica'],
 [6.1, 3.0, 4.9, 1.8, 'virginica'],
 [6.4, 2.8, 5.6, 2.1, 'virginica'],
 [7.2, 3.0, 5.8, 1.6, 'virginica'],
 [7.4, 2.8, 6.1, 1.9, 'virginica'],
 [7.9, 3.8, 6.4, 2.0, 'virginica'],
 [6.4, 2.8, 5.6, 2.2, 'virginica'],
 [6.3, 2.8, 5.1, 1.5, 'virginica'],
 [6.1, 2.6, 5.6, 1.4, 'virginica'],
 [7.7, 3.0, 6.1, 2.3, 'virginica'],
 [6.3, 3.4, 5.6, 2.4, 'virginica'],
 [6.4, 3.1, 5.5, 1.8, 'virginica'],
 [6.0, 3.0, 4.8, 1.8, 'virginica'],
 [6.9, 3.1, 5.4, 2.1, 'virginica'],
 [6.7, 3.1, 5.6, 2.4, 'virginica'],
 [6.9, 3.1, 5.1, 2.3, 'virginica'],
 [5.8, 2.7, 5.1, 1.9, 'virginica'],
 [6.8, 3.2, 5.9, 2.3, 'virginica'],
 [6.7, 3.3, 5.7, 2.5, 'virginica'],
 [6.7, 3.0, 5.2, 2.3, 'virginica'],
 [6.3, 2.5, 5.0, 1.9, 'virginica'],
 [6.5, 3.0, 5.2, 2.0, 'virginica'],
 [6.2, 3.4, 5.4, 2.3, 'virginica'],
 [5.9, 3.0, 5.1, 1.8, 'virginica']]


iris = pd.DataFrame(
    values, 
    columns='sepal_length sepal_width petal_length petal_width species'.split()
)
```

Comment: Could you add some data to your example so that others can run it. This line breaks your code `iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')`

Comment: @0x263A not sure why that breaks the code since it is part of the seaborn library, but I copy pasted the raw values and updated the question so you should have it now

Comment: Oh my apologies I was watching the new questions and missed that you imported seaborn as `sns`. Sorry about that, just so used to broken mvces.

Comment: The order of the columns and the rows is decided via the clustering.  Changing the order will break the clustering.  Without the clustering, you might simply draw a heatmap?

Comment: @JohanC ok, then can you make a heatmap with correct ordering of columns and dendogram and clustering for rows?

Comment: Just set `col_cluster=False` in `sns.clustermap`?

Comment: @JohanC no, that doesnt do it

Comment: @JohanC I still want a dendrogram though... just the first splits should be on category

Comment: Maybe you could calculate a custom linkage matrix, maybe by calling [scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html) multiple times and combining.  That matrix can then be provided as `col_linkage=` in `sns.clustermap`.  It would be quite some work and fiddling, though.

Comment: I think you probably should not show a dendrogram plot that is artificially manipulated to match a set of categories. It will actively mislead anyone who is familiar with this style of plot.